# Novel where humans discover God exists as a space entity periodically coming closer to Earth; they board an alien spaceship and attempt to kill him

Tags: story-identification, novel

Humans discover that God does in fact exist. He (or it in the novel) is an entity that lives in space, some distance from Earth. Every few hundred, or thousand years, God comes closer to Earth and these are the times when humans are most affected by God, the most religious times in Earth's history.

So, humans decide they will go out and kill God. To do this, they are using a spaceship they have somehow bought or stolen from an alien race. There are thousands of people on the ship. The children are generally raised not by their family but by a creche (essentially a group home for children). As the ship gets closer and closer to God, the people on board begin to lose their resolve.

Comment: Jeff Goldblum told me that mankind had already killed God in *Jurassic Park*. Surely Jeff Goldblum would not misinform me?

Answer (score 9):

I think it may be [*Shamanspace*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/548023.Shamanspace) (2002) by Steve Aylett.

> God has been found to exist and the race is on to take revenge...
>
> Opposing groups of occult assassins compete to exterminate the creator, with young gun Alix the favourite. As multidimensional war is waged, Alix travels through sidespace to confront the source of evil at the risk of destroying the universe.
>
> Shamanspace is an alchemical conspiracy adventure from Steve Aylett, author of Slaughtermatic and Atom.

[image: trippy pink and red cover depicting a face and glasses]

Answer (score 9):

I've been looking for a very similar book for a while now, and this question was the only thing that came up. I managed to track down the book I was looking for on my bookshelf.

It's called [Tides of God](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0441808948) (1989), by Ted Reynolds.

From [a Goodreads review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1773951493?book_show_action=true):

> In the 33rd century, after another round of Dark Ages, humanity has finally emerged with a utopian society built on the use of reason. Our more advanced alien allies loan us our first starship, on the condition that the crew hunt down and destroy a common enemy. The aliens tell us that this mysterious enemy is that long-forgotten entity, God. Twice before, it has passed Earth, each time driving us down into centuries of irrationality and bloody religious fanaticism, and it's headed back again. Now, if this were a James Morrow novel, that alien would actually be God. But in this, it is an unknown force that projects psychological belief in itself as God. Having no direct weapons, the projected madness is its only defense, as it causes the crew to turn on itself violently. Other than this one major innovative concept, the novel is a fairly routine space opera, with plenty of action and interpersonal intrigue. Somewhat more troubling, the author seems to have simply aligned several concepts without really examining their interrelationships, along the lines of reason=athiesm=libertarian sexual mores. At one point, I found myself cheering on the "breakdown" of the "rational" system of attachment-free sex. So while somewhat interesting in its portrayal of two extremes of human society, this book does not deserve the powerful acclaim implied by its cover blurbs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer? Mainly to outline what points match the OP's requirements.